# directx 9 setting a camra

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx-9

this is basic question.  im having touble setting the camra not how to set it but what values should i set it to.  is there any app that can help with setting camra like you set it and it gives you the values or can you explain what the values stand for and how to are they scaled.

```
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (value, value, value),    // the camera position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (value, value, value),      // the look-at position
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (value, value, value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `D3DXMatrixLookAtLH` function is generating a camera matrix, that gets stored in your `matView`.
After that, the function gets three vectors:

- position
- look-at
- up

Those three vectors stand for:

- the position of your camera - where your camera is. It could be (0,0,0) for example. (Those are your x, y and z coordinates in the world.)
- the look-at point - this is where your camera looks at. It consists of your position + your (usually) normalized view direction. So when you stand at (0,0,0) and want to look down the negative z-axis, your look-at point is (0,0,-1). If you stand at (1,2,3) and look down the negative x-axis, it's (0,2,3)
- the up-vector points up - normally this is (0,1,0).

If you move around now, without looking around, the position and the look-at vectors change to reflect your new position.
If you stand still and look around, only the look-at point changes.
The up-vector only changes if you roll the camera.

There are plenty of nice camera tutorials out there, that show you how to change those three vectors when looking around with the camera - for example [this one](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/camera.html).